# Can I open and execute a report in Visual Studio console application with no GUI controls

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I need to load and execute an existing Crystal Report in something like a console application. Basically update the data and save a copy out to a drive.

I've tried the crystal libraries I have installed but they all want a report viewer or some other GUI object.

Are there any SAP solutions that are capable of doing this ??

Comment: I found a similar question that may help you.  Check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029027/launch-a-crystal-report-from-a-c-sharp-console-application).

Comment: I think I have it working now. I moved to VS 2019 and noticed that one of the references  had the embed interop types set to true.  Here are the libraries I wound up using...

C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll

Thanks for your help !!